# Migration of seed not working after command is entered

Tags: php, database, sqlite

When attempting to use php artisan migrate command, I get the error

Tried searching similar questions posted, tried modifying the .env file, nothing.

I want the seed to be able to migrate when the command 'php artisan migrate --seed' is entered.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = database.sqlite and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message